# How to put an ImageView inside a CardView with border radius top?

Tags: android, android-cardview

My xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerMainCardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgRecyclerMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="5">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtRecyclerMainTheme"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtRecyclerMainNumberCommunity"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtRecyclerMainNumberArticles"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

That is my recycler_main_themes.xml which in inside a recycler view to display themes. The behavior of the image I'm looking for is to have the card with both left and right borders with 8dp radius, so I've put inside the MainActivity this:

```
cardView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.card_view_border);
```

And this is the card_view_border.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

But when the app runs, before the image is displayed, the cardView has both top borders with the radius then after the image is downloaded, the imageView overlaps the cardView and the card looks rectangular. Picture of how it is:

[image]

What am I missing to display it properly?

Edit: just to complement, I've tried many things such as changing the ImageView scaleType to `fitXY`, set `setPreventCornerOverlap(false)` on CardView, changing cardElevation on CardView and putting elevation on ImageView, but none succeeded.

Comment: this might be useful [image corner radious](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-with-rounded-corners)

Comment: Using vinc3m1 own RoundedImageView from his github does work, that was not the implementing I was searching for since it loads a whole library but it works really good and it is a very versatile way to customize later

Comment: So, I'm still accepting opinions of how to do it on other ways